# Traversing back to parent with lxml.html.xpath

Tags: python, lxml, lxml.html

How can we traverse back to parent in xpath?

I am crawling IMDB, to obtain genre of films, I am using

`elem =  hxs.xpath('//*[@id="titleStoryLine"]/div/h4[text()="Genres:"]')`

Now,the genres are listed as anchor links, which are siblings to this tag. how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select the parent element of the XPath expression you gave:

`//*[@id="titleStoryLine"]/div/h4[text()="Genres:"]/..`

Answer (score 2):

For lxml *only* (*not* the built-in ElementTree), the parent is in the element. You can get it like this:

```
parent = elem.getparent()
```

and then look from there for whatever you need.